# Change all strings to integers based on a rule in Python

Tags: python, string

I have an array with `string` elements such as:

```
[['2', '1', '1', '1', '4']
['4', '3', '3', '5', '6']
['7', '7', '2', '2', '7']]
```

and I want to get the result with `integer` elements as:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,1,1]
[1,1,0,0,1]]
```

Based on the rule that if the element is larger than 4, it is replaced with `1` else `0`

I tried to use a double loop in Python but it is too complex, is there any simple way to do this job?

Comment: I would just use a double `for` loop. It's only 2 loops.

Comment: I would also post my try...really helpful to you @flyingmouse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> L = [['2', '1', '1', '1', '4'],
        ['4', '3', '3', '5', '6'],
        ['7', '7', '2', '2', '7']]

>>> [[(1 if int(num)>4 else 0) for num in row] for row in L]

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension.

```
>>> l = [['2', '1', '1', '1', '4'],
['4', '3', '3', '5', '6'],
['7', '7', '2', '2', '7']]
>>> [[1 if int(j) > 4 else 0 for j in i] for i in l]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Traditional way..

```
final_list = []
for item in l:
    inner_list = []
    for inner_item in item:
        if int(inner_item) > 4:
            inner_list.append(1)
        else:
            inner_list.append(0)
    final_list.append(inner_list)

print final_list
```

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of this syntax. I would still use the double `for` loop for readability. But I guess it's subjective.

Comment: @Kris you may figure it out from my answer.. like `for i in l: for j in i: if ..`

Comment: I hear you. It's just a lot of encapsulation for a few lines of code. Generally, when you have logic within loops, I personally think its a bad idea to one-line it. Mistakes tend to come easier. Maybe not from you, but from others working in the codebase. Regardless, this is the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Another way like this

```
x = [['2', '1', '1', '1', '4'],
['4', '3', '3', '5', '6'],
['7', '7', '2', '2', '7']]

z = [map(lambda i: 1 if i > '4' else 0, y) for y in x]

print(z)
```

This obviously only works as long as all the values in the array are single figures. `'11' > '4'` returns `False`, which isn't what you want.

If you knew that any of the values in your array could potentially be `'10'` or above, it would be necessary to apply integer conversion to the values prior to the `> 4` (now also 4 is integer and not string) comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your input list is called `inp`
The double for loop works well:

```
out = [[0 for col in row] for row in inp]
for i, row in enumerate(inp):
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        out[i][j] =  int(int(value) > 4)
```

Or if you want a functional route with no for-loops (but less readable):

```
map(lambda y:  map(lambda x: int(int(x) > 4), y), inp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Double `for` loop will do the trick as well:

```
>>> l
[['2', '1', '1', '1', '4'], ['4', '3', '3', '5', '6'], ['7', '7', '2', '2', '7']]
>>> lout
[]
>>> for i,_ in enumerate(l):
    lout.append([])
    for j in range(len(_)):
        lout[i].append(1 if int(l[i][j]) > 4 else 0)
>>> lout
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

keep the list as list1, then use the lambda and map to solve this. And also we have to use the if else statement.
Atlast, save them in the another list as list2 and then print it.
You will get it..